# Mapping class group and fundamental group of a 3 manifold

Tags: 3-manifolds, mapping-class-groups

If the 3 manifold is Haken, then the natural homomorphism from the mapping class group of this 3 manifold to the outer automorphism of its fundamental group is an isomorphism.

Any other kind of 3 manifolds (assuming they are closed 3 manifolds) have this property? (I think hyperbolic 3 manifolds also have this property, but I am not sure.)

A more general question is: For which kind of 3 manifold , this natural homomorphism is injective (or surjective)?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is answered I believe in this survey paper of Hong and McCullough: http://www.ams.org/books/conm/597/11768/conm11768.pdf

Comment: For hyperbolic manifolds it follows from Mostow rigidity.